# "Довольный, как слон" — значение

Tags: фразеология

А почему — как слон? При чем тут слон?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Почитайте вот здесь: [Доволен как слон | Андрей Серебряков](http://saahov.ru/post/happy-elephant) 
Полная версия этой поговорки выглядит так: «доволен как слон после купания». То есть спустя какое-то время пословица превратилась в поговорку, из-за чего стало сложно её понять. А чтобы понять, почему слоны такие довольные, достаточно взглянуть на  фото автора (в этой же ссылке)

Есть ещё одно объяснение, оно касается сленга, где к слону относится не только "доволен", но и много чего ещё.Слон большой. Большие размеры слона зафиксированы в таких идиомах, как делать из мухи слона; слона-то я и не приметил. В идиоме слона-то я и не приметил большие размеры слона, из-за которых его действительно трудно не заметить, переосмысляются как нечто «важное», «главное». По происхождению это выражение цитата из басни И.А. Крылова «Любопытный» (1814). Слон большой и неуклюжий, тяжёлый, сильный, приятный, экзотичный (иностранец) Обращает на себя внимание отсутствие у слона психологических характеристик. В современном молодежном сленге, где большое количество выражений, характеризующих внутренний мир человека, имеют расширение «как слон» - довольный как слон, спокойный как слон, умный как слон, добрый как слон, веселый как слон, грустный как слон и т. п.Известно, что в русском языке конструкция «как + название животного» обозначает не собственно сравнение, а усиление признака или действия, названного прилагательным или глаголом: пить как лошадь значит «много пить»; хитрый как лиса - «очень хитрый» и т. п. 
И оказывается, что в современном молодежном сленге слон способен заменить любое из названий животных в этих выражениях: «Пришел солдат с войны к себе в деревню, ну и, понятно, врет, как слон»; «Предлагаешь молчать, как слон?»; «Вот и я боюсь размякнуть... меня вообще нельзя жалеть - начинаю реветь, как слон»; «Я когда в Австрии жил, тащился, как слон, от пивка местного с настоящих частных пивоварен» и т.д.Слон в сленге -  мера всех вещей.Поэтому и довольный как слон.

Comment: Совершенно верно.

Comment: Думается, не более чем "авторская версия" хозяина блога по ссылке. 
Лично мне поговорка кажется возникшей совершенно окказионально, никакого особого довольства за наcтоящими слонами - теми, которых могли наблюдать массово - не замечено.  Доказать не могу.  

А если уж где и копать, так надо бы покопаться в фене... СЛОН - это Соловецкий Лагерь Особого Назначения, может еще какое значение есть.

Comment: «Доволен как слон после купания» я слышала не раз. А насчёт лагерей - это одна из версий объяснения фразеологизма "Россия - родина слонов", но никак не "доволен как слон". Что-то в лагерях довольства не вижу. И второе объяснение - из серьёзной монографии по сленгу.

Comment: Я не предлагал С.Л.О.Н. как объяснение. Кстати для "Родина слонов" тоже весьма сомнительно.

Речь о другом. Интуитивно чувстыуется, что здесь не может быть такого простого объяснения (просто "довольный слон"), такие вещи обычно не приживаеются в языке. Либо случайное, либо что-то на поверхности совсем не лежащее, феня - как раз источник таких "подводных" объяснений.  

Ну и еще то, что оеально слона после купания могли видеть десяток человек из цирковой обслуги...

Comment: На фене СЛОН - как аббревиатура, или отмычка, или ещё что-то неподходящее, так что вряд ли оттуда."Родина слонов" - две версии - названная и ирония по поводу"советское - самое лучшее": "советский слон - лучший слон", отсюда сарказм "родина слонов". А "довольный как слон"употребляется именно в значении "очень довольный", не знаю, почему Вам не нравится объяснение 2 части моего ответа, взятого из диссертации учёного. Ну поспорьте с ним, только что-то Вашей версии не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

А как насчёт этого?
*- Хочется чего-то большого и чистого...

 - Слона после бани?*

Не помню, откуда шутка, но мне она представляется ещё одним аргументом к версии Людмилы.